# How to get data from 3 tables in one SELECT [MySQL]

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 different tables where based on search in first TABLE I am able to get data from second, and based on search from first and second I am able to get data from 3th table.

Tables looks like this:

```
table cases
+-------+----------+------------+---------+
|case_id| car_model|     vin    | country |
+-------+----------+------------+---------+
|  1    |    VW    |   ABCDEFG  |    EN   |
+-------+----------+------------+---------+
|  2    |    VW    |   GFEDCBA  |    PL   |
+-------+----------+------------+---------+
table calculations
+-------+---------------+------------+---------+
|case_id|calculation_id |    price   | country |
+-------+---------------+------------+---------+
|   1   |45545662512    |    11000   |    EN   |
+-------+---------------+------------+---------+
|   1   |45545662512    |     7000   |    PL   |
+-------+---------------+------------+---------+
|   2   |1234561234     |     3000   |    EN   |
+-------+---------------+------------+---------+
|   2   |3214561234     |     6000   |    EN   |
+-------+---------------+------------+---------+
table positions
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+
|case_id|repairmethod|    text    |calculation_id|
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+
|   1   |     L      |    hallo   |  7894561234  |
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+
|   1   |     L      |     hi1    |  45545662512 |
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+
|   2   |     L      |     hi2    |  45545662512 |
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+
|   2   |     E      |     hi3    |  45545662512 |
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+
|   2   |     G      |     hi4    |  45545662512 |
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+
|   2   |     L      |     hi5    |  3214561234  |
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+
|   2   |     L      |     hi6    |  3214561234  |
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+
```

How I wrote it:

- Get data and case_id from table number 1:

  "SELECT * FROM cases WHERE vin = :vin ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 60";
- Based on case_id I get from first table search in table number 2, take last row:

  "SELECT * FROM calculations WHERE case_id = :case AND country = :country ORDER BY calculation_id DESC LIMIT 1";
- Search in table number 3 based on case_id from table 1 and calculation_id from table 2:

  "SELECT text FROM positions WHERE calculation_id = :calculationid AND case_id = :case_id AND repairmethod LIKE 'L%' LIMIT 60";

Expected result if user search for ABCDEFG for example:

From table cases:

```
car_model = VW
country = EN
case_id = 1
```

From table calculations:

```
calculation_id = 45545662512    
price = 11 000
```

From table positions:

```
text = hi1
text = hi2
```

But this query is based on PHP , storing values in variabiles and so on, is there a chance to write all my previous statments in one SELECT?

I already try something with INNER JOIN

```
"SELECT * FROM cases v INNER JOIN calculations c
                    ON v.case_id = c.case_id
                    INNER JOIN positions p
                    ON v.case_id = p.case_id
                    WHERE v.vin = :vin
                    ORDER BY c.name DESC
                    LIMIT 4";
```

But there are multiple problem, with limits, with select with multiple WHEREs, and so on. Do I miss something?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Hi @ZoharPeled question edited, I can get to that result by with PHP storing variabiles, and I hope to skip this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT cases.case_id, cases.car_model, cases.country, 
       calculations.calculation_id, calculations.price, 
       positions.text 
FROM cases INNER JOIN
calculations ON(cases.case_id = calculations.case_id AND cases.country = calculations.country) INNER JOIN
positions ON(calculations.case_id = positions .case_id AND calculations.calculation_id = positions.calculation_id)
WHERE vin = :vin
```

Note: if you search for 'ABCDEFG', this will give you 2 rows of data, one for each record in positions table.

Comment: Hi Zohar, I just check it code definitly looks good and make sense, and when I use this SQL I get no error but output is blank :(

Comment: It works! I get no result becuase in my positions I didn't have any result for this statement.  I will have to figre it out but still one BIG THANKS! for your help